# Problem with responsive IMG tag: browser picking wrong size order

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First I would like to mention that I did read and check all the articles I could find here regarding this problem, but unfortunately none of them are clear enough or fix the issue for me.

There is no clear explanation + solution to this problem, and it's a really well sought after problem with images.

- Using `<picture>` tags I can achieve the purpose and the browser will
  load the correct image based on the max-width media specification.
- Using `<img />` tag the browser picks randomly regardless of the sizes
  or order of sizes specified.

In this scenario I am required to use the `<img />`. Consider the following code for a simple header image:

```
<img 
    width="1400px" height="230px" 
    class="page-header-image" alt="" 
    src="/wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-1.jpeg" 
    srcset="/wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-2.jpeg 1200w,
    /wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-3.jpeg 992w, 
    /wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-4.jpeg 768w,
    /wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-5.jpeg 576w, 
    /wp-content/uploads/z8poevCA-6.jpeg 230w" 
    sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, (min-width: 992px) 992px, (min-width: 768px) 768px, (min-width: 576px) 576px, (min-width: 230px), 230px" />
```

The above for me translates as:

- Default image size in src is width="1400px" height="230px" load: **z8poevCA-1**.jpeg
- XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up) load: **z8poevCA-1**.jpeg
- X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) load: **z8poevCA-2**.jpeg
- Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) load: **z8poevCA-3**.jpeg
- Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) load: **z8poevCA-4**.jpeg
- Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) load: **z8poevCA-5**.jpeg
- X-Small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) load: **z8poevCA-6**.jpeg

However, the browser will pick for example on a mobile screen of 400px the 1200w version of the image; which is wrong. The above works perfectly with `<picture`> tags, so I doubt the sizes as "wrong" - unless the `<img />` tags work differently.

The above is just an example, as I have tried many different combinations of sizes with the `<img />` tag; all went wrong. I also tried: https://responsivebreakpoints.com/ and whilst the tool is "cool" it's using `<picture>` and it's missing the sizes.

I would also like to mention that the document is using the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

And here is the CSS (if needed):

```
.page-header-image, .page-header-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%!important;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Demo:

```html
<img 
    width="1400px" height="230px" 
    class="page-header-image" alt="" 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/1400x230" 
    srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x200 1200w,
    https://via.placeholder.com/992x130 992w, 
    https://via.placeholder.com/768x100 768w,
    https://via.placeholder.com/576x90 576w, 
    https://via.placeholder.com/230x90 230w" 
    sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, (min-width: 992px) 992px, (min-width: 768px) 768px, (min-width: 576px) 576px, (min-width: 230px), 230px" />
```

Please shed some light onto this matter as this will help many users having this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet out of your code so we can see the problem for ourselves. Also what browser are you on and what OS and do you really mean it picks randomly, or that it picks consistently but not the image you were expecting?

Comment: @AHaworth Added snippet. The browser is Chrome (latest) and I`m on Win. It picks consistently but not the image it should.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Perhaps you could add the meta tag and give body 100vw width, just in case. However, as it is it seems to be working fine on Firefox on my Windows10 but not on Chrome/Edge (even with those things added). I can't at the moment find anything about this.

Comment: @AHaworth Indeed I could not find the reason/solution for this either. I`m starting to think about looking into the Chromium source...

Comment: I've made Chrome load the smaller one - but only if it hasnt already loaded the larger one, see my fuller explanation in a (sort of) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the given snippet in Firefox on Windows 10 the 'correct' size of image is shown each time for me (Windows 10).

However, on Chrome/Edge the larger image (1200px) was shown each time, however small I made the window (or the img element width).

This seems to be a cacheing issue.

If I clear the Chrome browser's cache and run the snippet on a window that is already small the correct image is shown and as I increase the window width the correct images are successively shown until it reaches the maximum one of 1200px.

If I then rerun the same experiment, the 1200px image is shown straight away. Somehow the browser is saying 'I've already got an image that is at least as large as the one wanted so I'll show that rather than get a smaller one'.

Hopefully someone can find a more formal description of what is going on.

Basically, your code is fine. The system (at least Chrome/Edge on W10) will only bother to go and fetch another image if it feels it has to, so the user isn't unnecessarily using their network allowance. I don't know if there's a way of telling other browsers like FF to do the same.

Comment: That's odd, I tried with "Disable Cache" option in the network tab without this result. Also, if this is the case... why does the <picture> method work fine?...

Comment: Well I suppose the picture could have completely different code. Have you managed to get the smaller images loaded by clearing the cache and running the snippet on a viewport that is already small (Chrome)?

Comment: I get the smaller image loaded if I run it already with a smaller viewport when I've disabled cache. Then as I increase the viewport size the larger ones come in in sequence as you've defined. However, if I then gradually make the viewport smaller it doesn't shift off the larger image being shown. But this isn't exactly cache I guess, in the sense it's the same instance being run, not picking up stuff left behind by a previous run.

Comment: I`m not sure how are you getting there results, for me both in Chrome and Firefox are the same. Just tested now and on a screen of 375 width I get the 758w image loaded. Cached, no cached, incognito, initial load, all the same.

Comment: I wonder if there is some setting in FF which is different? Also the important thing I found in Chrome was setting a narrow viewport, then clearing cache then running the code.